# SXA Search Performance

Tags: sxa, performance-optimization

I am using SXA 1.7, we are using 4 search results component in the page and we can find that the performance degrades after logging to the system with 10 users. IIS worker process is consuming about 93% of CPU utilization and when inspcet the requests in worker process we found that SXA search results elapsed time is increasing.

Is there any missing configuration that should be done to enhance the performance?

Comment: are you running single instance of sitecore on your machine?

Comment: It is a scaled environment, with 2 CD, 2 CM and one master SOLR and 2 slaves. but this request is taking too much time :https://{Site}/sxa/search/results/?l=ar-AE&s={7A5C6EEE-2BB0-40B4-BEE3-2F2520540A47}&itemid={CFC0CF4A-488E-4664-B4EB-1DCCFCA41C47}&sig=test&p=8&o=name,Descending&v={3FDA3D04-3AA5-4C48-AA3C-B8A9AB9CAEC2}